# Void type error on if statement when I add "&&"

Tags: java, typeerror, void

I write this:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Float result = 100f;

    if (jCheckBox1.isSelected() == true) {
    Float one = Float.valueOf(jTextField1.getText());
    result = result / one;


} else {}
```

and it works fine.

But when I add "`&& jTextField1.setDragEnabled(true)`" in the `if` statement I get '`void`' type error.

Why's that? And what can I do? Thanks.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to show the actual code that's failing and the exact error you get. Don't post working code and then describe some change that breaks it.

Comment: The type of the method `setDragEnabled()` is `void`. What did you expect would happen if you used it in the way you did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your code would look like this, with the added check:

```
if (jCheckBox1.isSelected() == true && jTextField1.setDragEnabled(true) == true) {
    Float one = Float.valueOf(jTextField1.getText());
    result = result / one;


} else {}
```

The problem is, that the setDragEnabled()-method probably does not return an object of boolean type, so the second check just doesn't make sence to the compiler.

So, a possible solution might be

1. Adjust the check (to whatever logic is needed in your case).
2. Adjust the method setDragEnabled(), so it returns a boolean (i.e true. in
       case, when the text field could be set dragable successfully and false otherwise)

Comment: I solved it. You were right on number 2. I had to make both statements "== true". Thank you very much!

Comment: BrainTrance, glad, I could help! Could you please accept the answer as correct?

Comment: the `== true` are useless

Answer (score 0):

Any `set` method never returns boolean result. Ideally every `setter` method returns void, which is not allowed type inside if condition in java.